# Laravel 5.6 Unit Test maintain login session from beginning until end

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, session-cookies

```
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->base_url = config('app.url');

        $response = $this->post($this->base_url . '/auth/login', [
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '123',
            ]);

        // how to get the login session cookie?
    }

    public function testStep1()
    {
        // how to set the login session to this POST request?

        $response = $this->post($this->base_url . '/step1', [
                'attr_1' => 'foo',
                'attr_2' => 'bar',
            ]);
        ...
    }

    public function testStep2()
    {
        // how to set the login session to this POST request?

        $response = $this->post($this->base_url . '/step2', [
                'attr_1' => 'abc',
                'attr_2' => 'xyz',
            ]);
        ...
    }
}
```

From the sample code above, what I want to achieve is `testStep1` & `testStep2` must in order *(wizard to create something)*. Thus, I must maintain the same session.

Is it possible to achieve?

### Edit 2018-07-10 14:51 UTC+8

I've tried the output after call the `/auth/login`, the value of `$response->headers->getCookies()` is

```
array:1 [
  0 => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie {#940
    #name: "XSRF-TOKEN"
    #value: "eyJpdiI6IjQwUKxYnZlQ0J3N1B0Vkp4VjBEWVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIj782RKOUh2UFhONFwvaVRPUm56YkJ1ekxxSXlCTmtYSFNyRUF3NTdCTWhBMHhEQis1VVU0OUFcL3pKQUcybTFwQjdad1I1em02V1d4bVhDZWR2NFluUTlxdz09IiwibWFjIjoiZWRjYjk2NWI1MTU3YmJlMGEwMDdiNjNkYmVkMjBjMWU3NTRmZjE5NmMyM2EwOTZlNWJmZmYwMmRmYmExMWE1MSJ9"
    #domain: null
    #expire: 1531218886
    #path: "/"
    #secure: false
    #httpOnly: false
    -raw: false
    -sameSite: null
  }
]
```

and the value of `$response` is

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse {#843
  +baseResponse: Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse {#1040
    #request: Illuminate\Http\Request {#856
      #json: null
      #convertedFiles: null
      #userResolver: Closure {#916
        class: "Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider"
        this: Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider {#52 …}
        parameters: {
          $guard: {
            default: null
          }
        }
        use: {
          $app: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#19 …}
        }
        file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthServiceProvider.php"
        line: "85 to 87"
      }
      #routeResolver: Closure {#860
        class: "Illuminate\Routing\Router"
        this: Illuminate\Routing\Router {#167 …}
        use: {
          $route: Illuminate\Routing\Route {#204 …}
        }
        file: "./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php"
        line: "527 to 529"
      }
      +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#870
        #parameters: []
      }
      +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#867
        #parameters: array:2 [
          "username" => "root"
          "password" => "123"
        ]
      }
      +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#911
        #parameters: []
      }
      +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#871
        #parameters: array:17 [
          "SERVER_NAME" => "localhost.com"
          "SERVER_PORT" => 80
          "HTTP_HOST" => "localhost.com"
          "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Symfony/3.X"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
          "HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET" => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
          "REMOTE_ADDR" => "127.0.0.1"
          "SCRIPT_NAME" => ""
          "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => ""
          "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
          "REQUEST_TIME" => 1531204718
          "PATH_INFO" => ""
          "REQUEST_METHOD" => "POST"
          "CONTENT_TYPE" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          "REQUEST_URI" => "/auth/login"
          "QUERY_STRING" => ""
        ]
      }
      +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#878
        #parameters: []
      }
      +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#869
        #parameters: []
      }
      +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#913
        #headers: array:6 [
          "host" => array:1 [
            0 => "localhost.com"
          ]
          "user-agent" => array:1 [
            0 => "Symfony/3.X"
          ]
          "accept" => array:1 [
            0 => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
          ]
          "accept-language" => array:1 [
            0 => "en-us,en;q=0.5"
          ]
          "accept-charset" => array:1 [
            0 => "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
          ]
          "content-type" => array:1 [
            0 => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          ]
        ]
        #cacheControl: []
      }
      #content: null
      #languages: null
      #charsets: null
      #encodings: null
      #acceptableContentTypes: null
      #pathInfo: "/auth/login"
      #requestUri: "/auth/login"
      #baseUrl: ""
      #basePath: null
      #method: "POST"
      #format: null
      #session: Illuminate\Session\EncryptedStore {#924
        #encrypter: Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter {#919
          #key: b"A╦k>ú8f\x10─ÌÜ8ØýxK\x01²┬Íî·»├\x1A³0▒S┘Ì"
          #cipher: "AES-256-CBC"
        }
        #id: "XPMgecNkwFHbZbujhiuEaBqgMqFTLIqsuIzyvXv"
        #name: "laravel_cookie"
        #attributes: array:11 [
          "_token" => "5lcOcLk9AqvSlWyLdHMKba1lJQ1UqD2rBBVCSav"
          "locale" => "en"
          "_previous" => array:1 [
            "url" => "http://localhost.com/auth/login"
          ]
          "_flash" => array:2 [
            "old" => []
            "new" => []
          ]
          "sess_user_id" => 123
          "sess_user_firstname" => "Foo"
          "sess_user_lastname" => "Bar"
          "sess_role" => "admin"
          "login_web_59ba36add234f940abcf014c987ea4e30989d" => 123
        ]
        #handler: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NullSessionHandler {#925
          -sessionName: null
          -prefetchId: null
          -prefetchData: null
          -newSessionId: null
          -igbinaryEmptyData: "\x00\x00\x00\x02\x14\x00"
        }
        #started: false
      }
      #locale: null
      #defaultLocale: "en"
      -isHostValid: true
      -isForwardedValid: true
      basePath: ""
      format: "html"
    }
    #session: Illuminate\Session\EncryptedStore {#924}
    #targetUrl: "http://localhost.com/dashboard"
    +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag {#1039
      #computedCacheControl: array:2 [
        "no-cache" => true
        "private" => true
      ]
      #cookies: array:1 [
        "" => array:1 [
          "/" => array:1 [
            "XSRF-TOKEN" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie {#940
              #name: "XSRF-TOKEN"
              #value: "eyJpdiI6IjVyVmRNSmlcL1dYK0VOdiwj8RxamZBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjNSQWFzcVllSEIrSYwZnNNbk1vZ1NERVc2UVdJeGs91D6UG5hNGlHUmRnendJOUVtUnA3Rnk0TnVLYmI5UnJXSTlZR3dxS0wxMElmOFlaWDMzdG9RPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI0ZTZlNTAwNjFkZWFkOTEwN2M1Y2EzMGRjOWMzMmU4NzEzNmM5NWU2MzhhODFjOGJkYTU0YmZlMTM3M2ExNmE3In0="
              #domain: null
              #expire: 1531219118
              #path: "/"
              #secure: false
              #httpOnly: false
              -raw: false
              -sameSite: null
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
      #headerNames: array:5 [
        "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
        "date" => "Date"
        "location" => "Location"
        "content-type" => "Content-Type"
        "set-cookie" => "Set-Cookie"
      ]
      #headers: array:4 [
        "cache-control" => array:1 [
          0 => "no-cache, private"
        ]
        "date" => array:1 [
          0 => "Tue, 10 Jul 2018 06:38:38 GMT"
        ]
        "location" => array:1 [
          0 => "http://localhost.com/dashboard"
        ]
        "content-type" => array:1 [
          0 => "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        ]
      ]
      #cacheControl: []
    }
    #content: """
      <!DOCTYPE html>\n
      <html>\n
          <head>\n
              <meta charset="UTF-8" />\n
              <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://localhost.com/dashboard" />\n
      \n
              <title>Redirecting to http://localhost.com/dashboard</title>\n
          </head>\n
          <body>\n
              Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost.com/dashboard">http://localhost.com/dashboard</a>.\n
          </body>\n
      </html>
      """
    #version: "1.1"
    #statusCode: 302
    #statusText: "Found"
    #charset: null
    +original: null
    +exception: null
  }
}
```

So obviously, the session cookie is not in `$response->headers->getCookies()`, and I don't use `actingAs()` is because after user successful login, will set a few session values, i.e. `sess_user_id`, `sess_user_firstname`, `sess_user_lastname`, `sess_role`...

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, are you testing endpoints for an API right?

Comment: @HCK ya, test for the Ajax API

Comment: you use Auth::attempt and middleware('auth') in routing right?

Comment: @PanupongKongarn, no, I use [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: did you try to use Mockito for mock the object?

Comment: You mean [this](http://site.mockito.org/)? This is for Java right? The build in testing framework in laravel would be enough

Comment: I will give you the example of my unittest (laravel 5.6)

Answer (score 3):

For the first case I would just make a post request and check if the cookie is present or not.

```
$response = $this->post($this->base_url . '/auth/login', [
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => '123',
            ]);
$response->assertCookieNotExpired($cookieName);
```

Note: you can get cookies from headers using. `$response->headers->getCookies();` but I don't think we need them in our case.

Now we know our authentication works we can use Laravel **actingAs** helper method for authentication and then make requests as follows.

```
    $user = // get your user.
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post($this->base_url . '/step1', [
            'attr_1' => 'foo',
            'attr_2' => 'bar',
        ]);
```

Make all kinds of assertion you like (check for cookies, sessions whatever you like)

```
$response->assertSessionHas($key, $value);
```

Before we move to the third case you should know that  it's better to test each section separately. In simple words your tests shouldn't depend on each other, so what we can do for the third case? We know our third case depends on the second and we have already the tested the previous processes. Now we just want to test if our third case is working or not. So why not we add the session values required for this request ourselves using Laravel helper **withSession**.

```
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                     ->withSession(['foo' => 'bar'])
                     ->post($this->base_url . '/step2', [
                           'attr_1' => 'abc',
                           'attr_2' => 'xyz',
                      ]);
```

Now you can again make assertions. Check list of all available [assertions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#available-assertions).

Comment: Bro, I've updated the question, I have tried `actingAs` before, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I can see the session values in dump.  use assertions like these         
       `$response->assertSessionHas('sess_user_id', '123');                 
        $response->assertSessionHas('sess_user_firstname', 'Foo');     
        $response->assertSessionHas('sess_role', 'admin');`

Comment: I think you not really sure what I want. I don't want to test the login whether is success. What I want is to test the `testStep1` & `testStep2`, the `testStep2` will use the session value that has set on `testStep1`, that's why I want to maintain the same session _(should be same session cookie)_

Comment: Ok so here is how you can you can get the values from session by using `$sessionStore = app('session.store');` and then `$sessionStore->get('sess_user_id')` it will return you the id. Add these after the you make a call. But you should read my last paragraph again. You should be only providing the data to tests not making them dependent on each other. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks bro, you're right, 2 tests dependent on each other are not consider as unit test. I will figure out other ways to do it.

Comment: Cool, as I mentioned you can use `withSession` helper and set all the required values in testStep2 and then validate the response.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/)  Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework for use in unit testing with PHPUnit

```
composer require mockery/mockery --dev
```

LoginController

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

            // Authentication passed...
            // Get the currently authenticated user...
            $user = Auth::user();



            return redirect()->route('profile');
        }else{
            return redirect()->intended('loginform');
        }
    }
```

Example Test

```
public function testLoginSuccess()
  {
      $credential = [
          'email' => 'xxx',
          'password' => 'yyy'
      ];

      Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')->once()->withAnyArgs()->andReturn(true);
      Auth::shouldReceive('user')->once()->withAnyArgs()->andReturn(true);

      $response = $this->post('/login',$credential);

      $response->assertRedirect('/profile');
  }
```

This example show you how to mock Auth Facades in unit test.

Auth::attempt return true
Auth::user return true

**You can use Mockery to mock object as you want.**

Comment: Thanks bro. I'm new to unit test, and I not really want to add in too many dependencies to the project. Anyway, from *Alley Shairu* comment, I should have 2 tests depends on each other, so I will find other ways to write the test

Answer (score 0):

Check phpunit.xml, by default the value of SESSION_DRIVER is set 'array', change it to 'file'